# What is the usage of these 12 kanjis (彁, 墸,壥,挧,暃,椦,槞,蟐,袮,閠,駲,妛)+18 more in modern Japanese? How to read it?

Tags: meaning, usage, kanji, archaic-language

[image]

I read from **[this interesting article](https://www.japantimes.co.jp/life/2018/10/29/language/ghost-kanji-lurk-japanese-lexicon/#.XAnSvMmKs0c)** that it's included in **[幽霊文字 (yuurei moji/ghost kanji (character)](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B9%BD%E9%9C%8A%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97)**. I tried to look up each of those kanjis:

I use these sites to look up those kanjis:

a.**[jisho.org](https://jisho.org)**

b.**[yahoo.jp](https://dic.yahoo.co.jp/search/)**

c.**[goo.ne.jp](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/srch)**

d.**[alc.co.jp](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?)**

**Here are the results:**

> 1.**jisho**: 彁 = (no known meaning; S&H uses jabberwocky words?)
>
> じゅんこ 【彁】 (Junko - unclassified name)
>
> yahoo: none
>
> goo.ne: none
>
> alc: none

My own observation: it might relate to: **謌 (uta/ka, sing or recite) ** and **彊 (彊 (kyō/tsuyo(i))** and **歌 (uta/ka, sing)**; which is カ、セイ?

> 2.**jisho**: 墸 = hesitate [ On: チョ ] (no sentence example)
>
> yahoo: none
>
> goo.ne: none
>
> alc: none

My own observation: it might relate to: **堵** (mistaken character) = fence, railing, enclosure.

> 3.**jisho**: 壥 =  fine residence, shop, store  [ On: テン ] (no sentence example)
>
> yahoo: none
>
> goo.ne: none
>
> alc: none
>
> 4.**jisho:** 挧 (Japanese horse chestnut?) [Kun:とち] [On:ウ]
>
> yahoo: none
>
> goo.ne: none
>
> alc: none
>
> 5.**jisho**: 暃 (be separated)  [On: ヒ]
>
> yahoo: none
>
> goo.ne: none
>
> alc: none
>
> 6.**jisho:** 椦 (wickerwork) Kun: まげもの On: ケン
>
> yahoo: none
>
> goo.ne: none
>
> alc: none

My observation: A mistake of **橳** ? or 群馬県に自生する妖怪というが、見つかっていない。

> 7.**jisho:** 槞 (cage)  On: ロウ (or ru)
>
> yahoo: none
>
> goo.ne: none
>
> alc: none
>
> 8.**jisho:** 蟐 (mantis, toad?(kokuji))
>
> **related**: 蟷螂 (かまきり) = praying mantis (esp. the narrow-winged mantis, Tenodera angustipennis)​. In kotobank, it's: **[カマキリ類の総称.](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E8%9F%90-1763858#E5.8B.95.E6.A4.8D.E7.89.A9.E5.90.8D.E3.82.88.E3.81.BF.E3.81.8B.E3.81.9F.E8.BE.9E.E5.85.B8.E3.80.80.E6.99.AE.E5.8F.8A.E7.89.88)**
>
> yahoo: none
>
> goo.ne: none
>
> alc: none
>
> 9.**jisho:** 袮 (ancestral shrine, embroidery) [On:デイ、 ネ、 チ]
>
> yahoo: none
>
> goo.ne: none
>
> alc: none
>
> 10.**jisho:** 閠 (intercalation, illegitimate throne) (Kun: うるう On:ケイ、 > ギョク、 ジュン). A mistake of **閏**?
>
> 11.**jisho: 駲** (horse's buttocks, horse's tail)  (On: シュウ、 ジュン)
>
> 12.**jisho**: 妛 (despise, contempt, ugly, same as)  (Kun: あなど.る、 おろ
>   か、 みにく.い、 みだる) (On: シ)
>
> All last three also don't have clear examples/usages.

Others:

- **垉**     ホウ     (Break; collapse)

  **汢**     ねた     (Marsh)

  **穃**     ヨウ     (No meaning??)

  **粫**     ジ、メン、うるち   (Gluten-free grain)

  **鍄**     キョウ、リョウ        Clamp

  **垈**     タイ、ダイ、ぬた   Wetlands

  **恷**     キュウ、ク      Be contrary; nice

  **熕**     おおづつ       Cannon

  **粐**     コ、ロ、ぬか     Rice-bran (pieces of grain husk separated from flour after milling.)

  **糘**     すくも        Chaff

  **鵈**     とび     Kite (bird)

  **岾**     はけ、やま      Mountain

  **橸**     まさ     Straight grain

  **碵**     いしずえ       Cornerstone

  **粭**     すくも        Chaff

  **膤**     セツ、そり、ゆき、たら    Snow

  **軅**     たか、やがて     After all       (A mistake of 軈?)

  **靹**     ケツ、とも      Archer's arm protector  (A mistake of 鞆?)

I find that these **'Japanese-only'** Kanji fascinating. I can only take a glimpse of its meaning through the parts. I take that these must be obscure characters since it's included in "Ghost Kanji Characters". I couldn't find these characters in Chinese Dictionary either even though these are considered "Kanjis".

**Here are my questions:**

> 1.What are the usages and word-pairs/collocation or sentence example that represent the meaning(s) of these Kanji? How do you use it? How
>   often?
>
> 2.As a native Japanese or a foreigner who lives for the longest time in Japan, have you used (or at least tried to use) these kanjis?
>
> 3.Is its usage only limited to **research or linguistics study**?
>
> 4.What does "**S&H** uses jabberwocky words" mean? Does it mean a **
>   nonsensical language aka nonsense word**? (what is **'S&H?'**)
>
> 5.Are all my assumptions correct? I mean the misintended character? Did I miss something?

**[Additional references](https://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E5%B9%BD%E9%9C%8A%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97)**

**Notes:**

Please help me to answer as thorough as possible so that we can contribute to this se. Short answer may suffice if you can summarize all the points well.

Thank you very much for all your answers!

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/35856/what-are-the-most-obscure-kanji/35857#35857

Comment: I might be misreading you, but isn't it in the definition of 幽霊漢字s that they're not actually ever used ?

Comment: @Yosh So, if I'm not misreading you, there's no usage of 幽霊漢字 at all? So, was it a mistake? Can we use this ghost kanji in, say, a novel or prose? What is your opinion about these kanji? Since it's been created, it seems to be just a waste to throw it away. Even the government didn't remove it from what I read in the article, instead, they make a new JIS character to represent the 'incorrect' one.

Comment: As far as I know 幽霊漢字 in the narrow sense was a mistake, but it took a while to determine if it was a mistake or not. (I can't afford time to explain more right now, and I might not be qualified at all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [wikipedia page](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B9%BD%E9%9C%8A%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97) you linked has a section about usage.

According to that, since the definition of ghost kanji is that there is no known usage, by definition, there is no past usage. After they appeared in the system by mistake, there has been some modern usage, but all examples mentioned in the article are misuse while trying to write a similar but different kanji. There are no truly intentional usage example mentioned in the article.

Comment: So, in conclusion, there's no real usage at all in real life, then? Hmm.. how about name usage? or probably alternative use of kanji? Have you ever encountered one in real-life usage? maybe something around you? I haven't found any though in close proximity.